# Error code 16 "CANCELLED" in react-native-google-sign-in

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-signin, sha1

I am trying to implement google sign in on my app and every thing running well , it ask me to choose account on press of sign in button but it response it send me code 16 "CANCELLED" error.

I've installed library by **npm install react-native-google-sign-in**.
Then I linked it. I created a new project on firebase and download google-services.json from there and paste it in android/app. Also generated release SHA1 and add in firebase project.

```
componentDidMount() {
   GoogleSignin.configure({
     //It is mandatory to call this method before attempting to call signIn()
     scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
     // Repleace with your webClientId generated from Firebase console
     webClientId:
       'my client id',
   });
 }
```

**Google sign in button and action**

```
   <TouchableOpacity 
     onPress={() => _signIn()}
     style={{height:50,width:50,borderRadius:50}}
   >
      <Image
       style={{height:50,width:50}}
        resizeMode='contain'
        source={ImagePath.GOOGLE_ICON}
     />
   </TouchableOpacity>

  _signIn = async () => {
    //Prompts a modal to let the user sign in into your application.
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({
        //Check if device has Google Play Services installed.
        //Always resolves to true on iOS.
        showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true,
      });
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      alert(JSON.stringify(userInfo))
      console.log('User Info --> ', userInfo);
      this.setState({ userInfo: userInfo });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Message', error.message);
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        console.log('User Cancelled the Login Flow');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        console.log('Signing In');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        console.log('Play Services Not Available or Outdated');
      } else {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error))
        console.log('Some Other Error Happened',error);
      }
    }
  };
```

**These are my signing config**

```
       release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
```

I expect successful google sign in and user data in response. Any kind of help will be appreciated.**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

- The fix to this is to add `SHA1` to the firebase.
- If you are testing for debug build then add `debug` SHA1 and for release build use `release` SHA1.
- After adding SHA1 certificate fingerprints to the firebase.
- Download and add the firebase `google-services.json` file to `/android/app/`

You can create a debug key by below command

- `cd android`
- `gradlew signingReport`

OR

```
cd android && ./gradlew signingReport
```

[Reference link](https://rnfirebase.io/)

Answer (score -1):

Please share your AndroidManifest.xml file.  Please check whether you have added any launch mode in manifest.  If so please remove.

Comment: No I didn't add any lauch mode.